# NPM - Add to package.json but don't install

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, npm, npm-install

I am wondering if it is possible to run a command that would check that the package is a valid npm package, add it to package.json as a dependency, but not install it.

I am doing this because I have a certain package installed globally and need to require it for an open source project. Hence, I wish it to be included.

Comment: No command for just adding IIRC, but you can always edit the json yourself. Note that having a package in the package.json has nothing to do with you `require()`ing that package in code.

Comment: I understand that difference. I would like it to be there because I rely on people to run `npm install` when they clone the repo.

Comment: Just manually add it to the `package.json` file then.

Comment: There's a really simple solution, look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75015023/2876202

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think yo can do that with npm. I've looked into the docs and I didn't find anything about.

You can use this as a workarround:

```
npm i <package> --save && npm uninstall <package>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 22):

The correct way to **only update package.json**, without any other side-effects is:

```
npm install --save --package-lock-only --no-package-lock <package>
```

Use `--package-lock-only` to prevent writing to node_modules.

> The **--package-lock-only** argument will only update the
>   package-lock.json, instead of checking node_modules and downloading
>   dependencies.

Then, use `--no-package-lock` to prevent the creation of the lock file:

> The **--no-package-lock** argument will prevent npm from creating a package-lock.json file. When running with package-lock's disabled npm
>   will not automatically prune your node modules when installing.

See [npm install docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) for more.

Comment: This is great, thank you, but it's odd there isn't a less roundabout way to do this.

Comment: Apparently this was a bug and it's fixed in npm 6.9.0 https://stackoverflow.com/a/54741955/1222240

Comment: @valepu It may have been put back then, as this is still working in npm v6.17.0 and in npm 8.

Answer (score -3):

If your package is installed globally, I don't know if npm would reinstall it if you run:

```
npm install --save foobar
```

That's what I would do to add it to package.json.

Comment: Are you saying if the package is present globally, npm eschews the local installation?

Comment: That's what he's saying, but he's wrong. `npm install foobar` will install `foobar` locally regardless of if it's already installed globally.

Comment: Sorry for my unfortunate answer then.
@EmileBergeron
So how do you set your package.json to use a dependency that's already installed on you computer ? Without editing the file

Comment: Why wouldn't you just edit the file manually? It's made to be easily editable... The `--save` flag is just a convenience.

Comment: It is not too much pain but I like to avoid doing things twice if I can. Opening the file, typing all that text that I need to memorize, making mistakes, troubleshooting, etc all lead to  potential time wasted.

Comment: Why would you answer with this? Didn't you read the question.