# How to npm install to only save dependency to package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm adding dependencies to a `package.json` that will be used as part of a provisioning process for a virtual machine. As such, I don't actually need to install the modules locally since the provisioner will do that for me inside the VM. So is there any way to do the following:

```
npm install --save <module>
```

So that it *only* creates a dependency for the latest version of the module in `package.json`  without actually downloading the module or creating a `node_modules` folder?

The `--dry-run` option is close, as it doesn't create a `node_modules` folder but it also doesn't write to `package.json` either.

For now, I'm manually doing the following each time I need to update packages before re-provisioning the VM:

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

Other reasons for this might include being able to easily build a `package.json` file in low-bandwidth situations such as tethering, where you know you'll need the module eventually but don't want to spare the bandwidth.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @GeigeV So far I've continued to use the "install and remove node_modules" approach. The low bandwidth solution seems to be very carefully checking the npm website for the current versions and manually adding them to your `package.json` file.

Comment: Combining the commands, whilst not an npm solution, does the trick as a one-liner:

`npm i <package> <package> <package> && rm -r node_modules`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to do that with `npm` that I'm aware of.

There are two npm packages for doing this; I've never used either of them, but they might be worth a try:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-add
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/adddep

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that both packages `npm-add` and `adddep` depend on the `npm` package which is enormous.

Comment: @AlexanderMills npm v6.9.0 is ~30MB on my machine

Comment: It's not really about the size for me. I use Docker to run NPM and NodeJS, but edit files on the host system. I don't want to install anything through NPM on my host system.

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these packages work with the latest version of npm. `npm-add` is locked to npm v1.2.18 and `adddep` (which was forked from npm-add) [doesn't work with npm v8.0.0 and above](https://github.com/19h/npm-adddep/issues/2).

Comment: Answer is outdated https://stackoverflow.com/a/73518727/2950649 should be accepted correct answer.

Answer (score 16):

Was searching for the solution. Haven't found, then made a script which adds dependencies (latest or specified versions) to the `package.json` file skipping the installation process.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/add-dependencies

#### Installation

If not using with `npx` (see below):

```sh
$ npm install add-dependencies [-g]
```

#### Usage

Run:

```sh
$ add-dependencies [package_file] <dependencies> [target] [--no-overwrite]
```

or with `npx`:

```sh
$ npx add-dependencies [package_file] <dependencies> [target] [--no-overwrite]
```

where `dependencies` is the list of dependencies divided by space, and `target` is one of the following:

- `--dev` / `--save-dev` / `-D` for `devDependencies`
- `--peer` / `--save-peer` / `-P` for `peerDependencies`
- `--optional` / `--save-optional` / `-O` for `optionalDependencies`

If no `target` argument passed, dependencies are written to `dependencies`.

If no `package_file` argument passed, the script searches for a `package.json` file within the current working directory.

Use `--no-overwrite` flag to prevent already existing packages in `package.json` from being overwritten.

Example:

```sh
$ add-dependencies /home/user/project/package.json moment@2.0.0 react@16.8 redux eslint --dev
```

or with `npx`:

```sh
$ npx add-dependencies /home/user/project/package.json moment@2.0.0 react@16.8 redux eslint --dev
```

---

Hope this could help someone else.

Answer (score 13):

Interestingly combining `--package-lock-only` with `--no-package-lock` seems to do this

```
npm install --package-lock-only --no-package-lock PACKAGE
```

This does not create or update the package-lock.json file. Only adds an entry to the package.json

UPDATE

This was actually a bug and is now fixed in npm 6.9.0

https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/146

https://npm.community/t/release-npm-6-9-0/5911

Comment: This was a bug and is now fixed in npm 6.9.0... https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/146

Comment: uhm too bad... I've hardly ever seen a more blatant case of "it's not a bug... it's a feature"

Comment: Is it really a bug? When I run `npm install --package-lock-only --no-package-lock PACKAGE`, I don't get any `node_modules` directory. Using npm 6.9.0

Comment: Is it confirmed if its a bug or not?? I'm using the same on ```6.7.0``` and its working fine

Comment: npm version 7.7.6 - Works! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As of Npm > 8 the correct answer is

```
npm pkg set devDependencies.rollup="*" devDependencies.typescript="4.5"
```

Explaination `npm pkg set` can change your current package.json

see: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-pkg

Answer (score 0):

I made a very **simple** way to do this.

Add this to the `scripts` section of your `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "no-dl": "npm install --package-lock-only --no-package-lock"
  }
```

Then use it like this:

```
npm run no-dl <package-name>
```

I've called it `no-dl` — pick your own name as needed.

Answer (score -2):

`npm install --save packagename` then `npm uninstall packagename` (without --save flag) accomplishes this, though an empty node_modules folder is created

Comment: This doesn't work in Node 5+ because the `--save` flag is implicit.

Comment: `--save` is only implicit for install, not for uninstall. Using --no-save is also an option. This isn't a solution for your low-bandwidth scenario either way, as it unnecessarily downloads the package contents