# npm install command - only change package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

When we do:

```
npm install lodash
```

it will update package.json and install the dep to node_modules.

My question is - is there an npm flag that tells npm only to update the package.json file, and not to change node_modules?

Something like:

```
npm add lodash
```

I filed a **ticket** with NPM on GIthub for this issue:
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/21065

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40535328/how-to-npm-install-to-only-save-dependency-to-package-json

Comment: thanks, I filed a ticket with NPM on GIthub for this issue:
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/21065